# Subscribing topic function in callback function

Tags: python, mqtt

I have a little problem with understanding the `on_connect()` callback function in Paho Mqtt client.

```
def connectionStatus(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe("facialrecognition/reset")


  client.on_connect = connectionStatus
```

So, when connection with broker will be established. Function `connectionStatus()` will cause start subscribing to topic `"facialrecognition/reset"`? Do I understand understand correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python) that would be happen, but remember to do it as below:

```
def connectionStatus(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe("facialrecognition/reset")

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = connectionStatus
```

Besides, you can find more examples in the [github repo](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python)